# How to make Child Component Form wait before it submits its Form data for the Parent Component to have done submitting its own/separate Form?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

How to make ChildComponent wait and collect the ID from newly submitted ParentComponent Form and only ^then^, after the ID has been collected, feed that ID to the Child Component Form and then submit Child Component Form ?

Child and Parent Components are communicating through @Output and BehaviorSubject.

1. HTML Parent template -> https://pastecode.io/s/8zichk9g
2. Typescript -> https://pastecode.io/s/nj3q21ug

This is the visual representation of Parent and Child Form Submition from my App:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ejahr2imrehoblrse6l5w/save-nested-tasks.mkv?dl=0&rlkey=0x8rv4ts924tj116p7rqxntt6

As it is now, ParentComponent and ChildComponent submit methods are performed simoutaneulsy, which is wrong, I need 'onTaskSubmit' method to wait for the 'onGoalSubmit' method to funish submitting:

```
onGoalSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    this.priorityValue = this.priority.nativeElement.querySelector('.active').innerText;
    this.newGoal = new Goal(
        form.value.name, 
        form.value.isMainGoal, 
        form.value.details, 
        form.value.select_category, 
        this.priorityValue, 
        form.value.creationDate, 
        form.value.endDate
    );
    this.newGoal$ = this.goalsS.postGoal(this.newGoal);
    this.newGoal$.subscribe((response: any) => {});
    // ...other stuff here like removing modal 
    // and component refreshing
}

onTaskSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.newTask = new Task(
        this.newGoalId, // This is the place where I need to paste my new Goal ID
        form.value.name, 
        form.value.description, 
        form.value.priority, 
        form.value.taskDate
    );
    this.tasksS.postTask(this.newTask);
}
```

Do I need the Async Pipe somewhere - but where and how ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have your `newGoal` value inside the `newGoal$` BehaviorSubject what you can do is to store the data you get from your `onTaskSubmit` function in another Subject and then use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) or [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) rxjs operators to combine these two.

Another combine option is to use [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) and get the data you want from the `newGoal$` Subject.

Comment: Thank you, I will try out your suggestions